# Vector triple product = 0

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Let $U, V, W$ be three non-zero vectors, no two of which are parallel.

Under what conditions is $U\times(V\times W) = 0$?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3):

The construction $U\times(V\times W)$ will be zero if $U$ is collinear to $V\times W$.

Comment: An added note to @john: since $V\times W$ is perpendicular to $V$ and $W$, this means that the product is zero if $U$ is perpendicular to the plane spanned by $V$ and $W$.

Comment: t h a n k s that +1

Answer (score 2):

The triple product will be zero if $U$ is perpendicular to the plane containing $V$ and $W$. This is equivalent to janmarqz' answer, but my answer doesn't assume that you know anything about $V \times W$.

Comment: That is, iff $U\cdot V=U\cdot W=0$.

Comment: Good point. So, an even simpler statement is: the triple product will be zero iff $U$ is perpendicular to both $V$ and $W$.

Answer (score 1):

In **A**X(**B**X**C**), if all the vectors parallel or if **B** and **C** are parallel or if **A** is parallel to **B**X**C** (or **A** is perpendicular to the plane defined by **B** and **C**, then the vector triple product will be a null vector.